How do I switch from Drawer navigation to Stack navigation
I need to switch from Drawer navigation to Stack navigation but cannot seem to get rid of the
Drawer


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const ShipmentStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="SelectAccount" component={SelectAccount} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ShipmentList" component={ShipmentList} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ShipmentDetail" component={ShipmentDetail} options={{ title: "Shipment Details", headerShown: true }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const DrawerStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer

      independent={true}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="SelectAccount"
        backBehavior="history"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStatusBarHeight: 0,
          headerShown: true,
          unmountOnBlur: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.lightGreen,
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: 'black',
            fontFamily: 'NunitoSans',
          }
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={ShipmentStack}
          options={{ //change the configuration of our screen
            drawerIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => { //set the icon:
              return ( //the icon will be an image
                <Image
                  source={require("../assets/images/home_icon.png")}
                  style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="About"
          component={About}
          options={{ //change the configuration of our screen
            drawerIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => { //set the icon:
              return ( //the icon will be an image
                <Image
                  source={require("../assets/images/about_icon.png")}
                  style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Contact"
          component={Contact}
          options={{ //change the configuration of our screen
            drawerIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => { //set the icon:
              return ( //the icon will be an image
                <Image
                  source={require("../assets/images/contact_icon.png")}
                  style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

